# If $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ are such that $x^2+x=y^2$, $y^2+y=z^2$ and $z^2+z=x^2$, prove that $(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)=1.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x,y,z$ are real numbers that not equal to 0 such that $x^2+x=y^2$, $y^2+y=z^2$ and $z^2+z=x^2$ prove that $(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)=1$.
I solve this problem by adding each two equations, but I'm interested can we solve this problem by subtracting equations? By subtracting we get $(x-y)(x+y+1)=(y-z)(y+z)$.

Comment: Try to rearrange terms in equations and multiply them.

Comment: I get (x+y)(y+z)(z+x)=(x+y+1)(y+z+1)(x+z+1) and i have x+y+z=0 but don't know if i can finish the problem with that way

Answer (score 3):

Adding the three equations we get
$$x+y+z=0.$$

So then, if we rewrite the equations as $y^2-x^2=x$, $z^2-y^2=y$, etc., we find $(y+x)(y-x)=x$, $(z+y)(z-y)=y$, $(x+z)(x-z)=z$, which in view of the above relation we can rewrite as $(x-y)z=x$, $(y-z)x=y$, $(z-x)y=z$. Multiplying these three equations, and using that $xyz \neq 0$, we get the desired conclusion.

Comment: Ok i know for that variant of solution but i'm interested can we solve differently(by subtracting pairs of equations)?

Comment: I don't know how to rule it out, but it does not seem likely to me. When you subtract you get equations like $(x−y)(x+y+1)=(y−z)(y+z)$, which gives you expressions for $(x-y)/(y-z)$, etc. I don't really see how that helps towards establishing the product that you are after.